# Will Android 2.2 apps work on Tablets running on 3.0 and higher version

Tags: android-3.0-honeycomb, android

My basic question is : Will developing android apps with android 2.2 SDK work for android tablets running on Honeycomb (android 3.0) and higher versions ?

Also, will apps developed for phones work on tablets ?

Adithya.

Comment: Android has forward compatibility, the apps will probably look a little bit weird though because of different resolutions. [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160048/forward-or-backward-compatibility-in-android) [Android info](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html) Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can have the same apk work with 2.x and 3.x. Just use something like this in your manifest xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

If you have created a virtual android tablet you can test it on a tablet emulator, just right click your eclipse project, Run as -> Run Configurations, then check android 3.0+ in target tab.

For more info see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html#Optimizing

Comment: ok. one question over here : android:targetSdkVersion="11" along with android:minSdkVersion="4" specifies that all compatibilty features are disabled and new features (pertaining to the target version) are available for the target version (i.e. 11) only (source : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) but the app will work on all versions from "4" and above and not necessarily limit itself upto "11" .Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, apps are forward compatible, so this makes it work on the old versions as well as the new tablet os.

Answer (score 1):

As to the first they should, it's supposed to be forward compatible.

Having said that depending on how you developed you app it's possible that you are making use of features not present on the tablet.  I have had apps that work on phones tank when I tried them on the tablet, mostly because I was not checking feature sets properly (mostly in the camera) so you do have to take some care.

Really this is not a tablet issue, more of a supported hardware issue but it becomes pretty apparent on those, many don't have cameras for instance, some don't have GPS etc.

As to the second, yes, but they won't be optimized for the tablet so your users might not like tiny images if you have not provided for higher resolution screens

Comment: will specifying the android:targetSdkVersion help in any way ?

Comment: It won't change anything other than to tell the market place the minimum SDK level you can run on, you can also specify target SDK so that a later operating system can optimize the app, but I have never seen that matter. You just have to test it on an emulator with OS targets, and hardware specs

Answer (score -1):

I think no. Devices with Android 3.0 ang higher have xLargeScreen resolutions. And Android 2.2 doesn't have support for this. Only Android 2.3+