# Examples of forward incompatibility of the Android framework

Tags: android, compatibility, forward-compatibility

For a report on Android fragmentation, I am researching about forward compatibility of the Android framework/SDK.

It is widely stated, that the Android SDK is forward compatible, meaning, that applications developed with one framework will run on devices, that are running a later one, i.e. on [Forward or Backward Compatibility in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160048/forward-or-backward-compatibility-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top). When a feature or API is deprecated it is mostly stated on developer.android.com, that the feature will continue to work on devices, i.e. [Google Maps Android v1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/).

Now, I experienced myself a case of incompatibility with Text-to-speech, when running a 2.2 application on to 4.1. This case is portrait here [Text to Speech not working in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558337/text-to-speech-not-working-in-android-4-2-jelly-bean). (Shortly, you are not supposed to check for the availability of TTS before using it anymore, because the existence of TTS on a device is mandatory from 4.1 onwards. And in fact, this check will falsely return false on 4.1, so your code that was written for on 2.x is not working properly on 4.1 onwards.)

Are there any other examples when an App or one of its functionalities stop working on a later version (apart from Apps developed for 1.x)? What are the specific deprecated features/APIs that make troubles on newer devices?